# getting a 403 error

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions

Constantly getting a 403 error.

```
You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.
```

log file :

```
(13)Permission denied: access to /index.html denied
(13)Permission denied: access to /favicon.ico denied
```

directory permissions (/home/www/eric/cascade)

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 eric www  193 Jan 28 17:38 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x 2 eric www 4096 Jan 28 18:27 images
-rwxr-xr-x 1 eric www 3715 Jan 28 18:27 index.html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 eric www  753 Jan 28 17:38 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 eric www 4096 Jan 28 18:25 js
-rwxr-xr-x 1 eric www 2258 Jan 28 18:27 oops.html
```

Configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost 50.57.104.245:80>
    ServerName dev.cascaderisermanagement.com
    DocumentRoot /home/eric/cascade/public

    <Directory "/home/eric/cascade/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from ALL
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it possible that apache cant access www group ?? How do  I check / verify ??

Comment: +1 for details provided from the outset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some leads to try following:

Regarding file permissions, the permissions of every parent directory matter too. They must all have execute permission (meaning "search" for directories).

```
ls -l / /home /home/eric /home/eric/cascade
```

To check easily, you could su to the user apache is running as and try catting the file, e.g,

```
sudo -u nobody cat /home/eric/cascade/public/index.html
```

And the group doesn't matter if the world permissions are more inclusive anyway.

Also, what's in that `.htaccess` file? I noticed you enabled them with `AllowOverride` and there's one in that directory.

Comment: Yup, definitely need to check out the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks a ton guys. . .  it turned out that the parent directory /home/eric was d-wx------

Answer (score 0):

Error 13 indicates a [filesystem level](http://www.barricane.com/c-error-codes-include-errno) "permission denied".

If you have a `Deny` directive in your configuration, you get a different line in your error logs.  Here are some examples.

Using a `Deny`:

```
Feb  4 10:44:08 host apache2[7907]: [error] [client 192.168.1.1] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/site/index.php
```

Using `chmod 000` on the directory (with `AllowOverride` turned on):

```
Feb  4 10:44:23 host apache2[7902]: [crit] [client 192.168.1.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/site/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

Using `chmod 000` on a static file:

```
Feb  4 10:51:15 host apache2[7905]: [error] [client 192.168.1.1] (13)Permission denied: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/site/favicon.ico
```

Using `chmod 000` on a PHP file:

```
Feb  4 10:43:54 host apache2[7900]: PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
Feb  4 10:43:54 host apache2[7900]: PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/site/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

You may notice that in all the error (13) cases, the full file path was given in the error message, not a relative URI.  That means that in your case, Apache is trying to read `index.html` from the root of your filesystem, not `/home/eric/cascade/public/`.

I suspect you have another vhost somewhere that has a `DocumentRoot` of /.  To confirm this, you could add `AccessLog` and `ErrorLog` directives to that vhost pointing to a different location.  You can also use this command:

```
apache2ctl -S
```

To help figure out what vhosts you have and what order they are applied in.